# Get selected cell value, row, and column from Excel

Tags: javascript, c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

Just looking to be pointed in the right direction about how I should do this.

Background: Creating a program which will automatically fill out excel pricing files for our customers from our database based on the UPC. However, there's over a hundred different sheets because customers want them sent in their own format. Some in very weird formats. I don't want to hard code the columns/locations for UPC, price, etc. (sections that need to be filled out), as the sheets sometimes change and we get new customers.  Therefore, I'm going to put the power in the users hands to map the locations of the UPC column, etc.  I currently use excel interop in C# to do the excel file reading/filling out, however the mapping user panel is what I need help with.

What I would like to do: I'm comfortable with modifying an excel file in the background.  However, I would like the mapping to work as such.  I could easily say: "UPC Column Header" and the user puts in B10 in a text box and so on.  What I would rather do is have the previous mappings for that customer in the text boxes, a check to see if the text is the same (same cell text value as before), and then an error if the column header cell text doesn't match the previous mapping stored in a db.  I'm fine and dandy with the database portion to store/check the mappings, but here is my conundrum... and I may be putting more work on myself.

The conundrum is: I would like the user to be able to view the selected excel sheet and click on a cell to select a new mapping in the program, or to map a new excel sheet.  So it would say: "Click the UPC header," and so on in order to fill out the mapping form.  How would you go about this?

I'm a C#/ASP.NET web developer with decent Javascript experience and would like to keep it as a web app (to avoid having to update the program based on my changes for the user).  However, I'm willing to go down different avenues/languages.

Comment: Moreso asking for a way to get the value, row, and column of a user selection from excel into a text box in a program "on the fly."  I'm already using excel interop to do manipulations.  I'm going down an ASP.NET/C# route, because that's what I know, however I am interested in a way to grab user selection from Excel as I don't know how I can do it with the path I'm going down.  I'd like to open the sheet for them or embed it in the page to grab their selections when mapping a new pricing file.  I'm sorry if it doesn't make sense!  I tried to explain best I can as to why I want to do this.

Comment: How complex is each sheet? I might have misunderstood, but could you have the user upload the Excel sheet, have your program convert it into a HTML table, and add listeners/text fields to each HTML cell so the user can interact with it?

Comment: It can be complex, but mostly they differ heavily.  Basically I would like the user to be able to say "this is the UPC column, this is the promo price col., this is the promo start date col., this is where they want this county's pricing to start, this is where they want their store numbers, etc."  Some send pricing and only want promotional pricing for the UPC's they send--not just letting me fill all of the pricing from my db.  Then ask for some more input that I would need as a mapping that could be 250+ rows down.  It would be a lot stuff to put in an HTML table.

Comment: The process sounds cumbersome. If I were your client, I wouldn't want to go through the sheet "twice" (once to enter actual data, and again to point out where each type of data is located). Also, are you sure that you can store these locations? Does each customer always enter data in the same locations?

Comment: Well, it's for the company I work for.  Basically someone sits there and fills these out manually.  The pricing data would be entered programmatically based on our point-of-sale system's database. Secondly, the sheets don't change too often as to where the data is located, but they do change.  That's when I would like them to select the customer (their cell mappings are stored from the last time), browse/select a file, check that the cell mappings have the same text as last time (to determine if the sheet changed), and allow the user to select a new mapping if the sheet changed from last time.

Comment: Do you really mean "interop" or do you mean an "Office add-in" using the JavaScript APIs? That makes a big difference in how to answer - and how to tag.

Comment: I mean the Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll for C#, but like I said--I'm willing to take different avenues if need be.  I don't think it will work for the clicking on cells because it should need to be an active language like js.